# Return type from Axios in TypeScript is incorrect when using await/async

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

UPDATE: this is not a problem with Axios or TypeScript but some strange IDE configuration issue. Recreating the environment and .idea folder from scratch made it go away.

When using Axios with TypeScript, using async/await operators (versus promises) seems to make the type inferred by TypeScript incorrect. For example doing:

```
let res = await Axios.get<Case[]>('/stack');
console.log(res);
```

I would expect the return type of res to be **AxiosResponse<Case[]>**
However TypeScript infers the type as simple **Case[]**
Logging to console, I can confirm that indeed the response is an AxiosResponse object with the data property being of type **Case[**]

[image]

TypeScript compiler (and IDE) interpret return type as just an Array of Case objects

[image]

Note that if I use promises instead then behaviour is as expected (i.e. use .then and .finally and not await)

**UPDATE:** So after comments from people that this did not happen to them, I tried to recreate the project and interestingly this problem does not occur:

[image]

However, I still have no idea what makes it happen in the other project. Note it is not IDE related as it will happen in VS Code too. I tried to completely nuke node_modules, package-lock, node cache and reinstall everything and it continues to occur. Same TypeScript and Axios version in both projects.

Comment: Per [the type definition](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L140) the get method should indeed return a promise of a response object, and that's the type I get when I await `Axios.get`. Could you give a [mre]? Also note you probably shouldn't expose the transport layer outside that method, i.e. `AxiosResponse` shouldn't be something other parts of your code know about.

Comment: Your code works as you expect [in the typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/RwRAvW).

Comment: The example is stripped for simplicity. I actually only want to check AxiosResponse for status code. If this is not easily reproducible then I suspect it is some envrionmental error. I will experiment to create a new environment and see. Thanks for playground example.

Comment: Ok I recreated project from scratch and problem goes away. Super weird. I will try figure out why but it is not a problem with Axios or TS then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else with this issue, I tried a thousand things and in the end there was a problem with the .idea directory created with the IDE. I am not sure what, specifically, but deleting the whole .idea folder and reloading the project fixed everything. Weird.